# issue in calling upload hook in file upload

Tags: perl, file-upload, drag-and-drop, cgi

I am trying a file upload by drag and drop.For this ui side i have used blueimp file upload plugin and server side i am using the same upload.cgi that i am using for simple browse and file upload.Issue i am facing is in my main method of cgi hook method is not getting called :-

```
$cgi = CGI->new(\&hook, "file_upload");
```

here control is not going in hook method.

```
sub hook
{
  &logMsg("In Hook1");
  my ($name, $buffer, $bytesRead, $data) = @_;
  &logMsg("In Hook");
  &logMsg("name=$name,bytesRead=$bytesRead");
  if (defined $lastSeenName)
  {
    if (($name ne $lastSeenName) || ($bytesRead < $lastSeenTotal))
    {
      $subTotal += $lastSeenTotal;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $uploadSize = $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'};
    &logPct(0);
  }

  $lastSeenName = $name;
  $lastSeenTotal = $bytesRead;
  $fileSizeMap{$name} = $bytesRead;
  $totalBytes = $subTotal + $bytesRead;

  if ($uploadSize > 0)
  {
    my $curPct = int((100 * $totalBytes)/$uploadSize);
    $curPct = 98 if ($curPct > 98);
    &logPct($curPct);
  }
}
```

when i am using my using my old style browse and upload file hook method is getting called.Can anybody let me know in what i am missing and why hook method is not getting called.

Thanks,
Manish